# Get Windows Locale code from preferred language

Tags: c, macos, cocoa

How can I get the windows locale code from from the first preferredLanguages?

Currently, it return me 12 (in decimal) which doesn't correspond to any windows locale (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oe376/6c085406-a698-4e12-9d4d-c3b0ee3dbc4a)

```c
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

int main() {
    CFArrayRef preferredLanguages = CFLocaleCopyPreferredLanguages();

    if (CFArrayGetCount(preferredLanguages) > 0) {
        CFStringRef firstLanguage = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(preferredLanguages, 0);
        CFLocaleIdentifier localeIdentifier = CFLocaleCreateCanonicalLanguageIdentifierFromString(NULL, firstLanguage);
        uint32_t windowsLocaleCode = CFLocaleGetWindowsLocaleCodeFromLocaleIdentifier(localeIdentifier);

        printf("Windows locale code %d.\n", windowsLocaleCode);
    } else {
        printf("No preferred languages found.\n");
    }

    CFRelease(preferredLanguages);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: MacOS or Windows? Please make up your mind.

Comment: `"%d"` is not the correct conversion specifier for an `uint32_t` -  `"%" PRIu32` would be.

Comment: So looking for a Windows locale code, or "a window's locale code"??

Comment: @Jabberwocky, It's code for MacOS that's supposed to return the code Windows uses. ("Returns a Windows locale code from the locale identifier.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`https://ss64.com/locale.html`](https://ss64.com/locale.html) appears more complete, and lists 12 as `fr` (French). Based on your very French user name, that seems to be a a very sensible result. So your code appears to work.<sup>[1]</sup> You are simply looking at the incorrect documentation, or the documentation is incomplete.

---

1. But it's not correct. `%d` is not the correct conversion specifier for an `uint32_t`. You can use

   ```c
   #include <inttypes.h>

   printf( "%" PRIu32 ".\n", windowsLocaleCode );
   ```

Comment: Thank you. Like you said, I was looking to an incomplete doc. Thank you for providing the right doc!

Comment: I wouldn't say that the right doc, just one that helped here.